Solving a recursion formula involving products of compositions of an integer
I have the following recursive formula that I want to solve in order to find a general, non-recursive expression for arbitrary $S_N$ (real positive number). Here it is:
\begin{equation*}
S_{N+1} = \frac {1}{N+1} \sum_{r=1}^N 2^{-r} \sum_{j_1+j_2+\dots+j_r=N} S_{j_1} \cdot S_{j_2} \cdots S_{j_r} \qquad \text{with} \quad S_1=1
\end{equation*}
where the second sum runs over all possible compositions of $N$ into $r$ parts, and $S_{j_1} \cdot S_{j_2} \cdots S_{j_r}$ is the product in the conventional sense.
I am not very familiar with this kind of recursions. I attempted to plug-in a generating function but with no success. Any advice on how to unpack the recursion? Obtaining the scaling of $S_N$ with respect to $N$ would already be a success :)
Edit: I add the first 12 values for $S_N$, maybe we can spot a pattern?
1, 1/4, 5/72, 11/576, 479/86400, 1769/1036800, 34091/60963840, 943633/4877107200, 92107357/1316818944000, 688988827/26336378880000, 38413345661/3824042213376000, 1806750541927/458885065605120000

Have you tried computing some values for small $N.$ You might see a pattern.

@ThomasAndrews I attempted to plot the first numbers to identify a scaling behavior. But unfortunately I am not been able to prove the correctness of this scaling by plugging it in the recursion...

Well, why didn't you share those values with us? Help people help you. Anything you already know and have tried we should know, so we don't repeat work you've already done or tried.

@ThomasAndrews
These are the first 20 values for $S_N$, does it help in any way? Unfortunately, this is not a sequence of intergers...
1, 0.25, 0.125, 0.078125, 0.0546875, 0.041015625, 0.03222656250000001, 0.02618408203125, 0.02182006835937499, 0.018547058105468833, 0.0160179138183595, 0.01401567459106445, 0.012398481369018792, 0.011070072650909413, 0.009963065385817418, 0.009029028005897976, 0.008232349064204007, 0.007546319975517155, 0.00695055787218649, 0.006429266031771898

Put in in the question. The reader shouldn't have to red the comments to know. And it might help to have the actual values, not a decimal approximation.

@ThomasAndrews
Edited! Is it possible to spot a pattern? Denominators are clearly powers of 2, but for the rest, I cannot extract a rule...

The factors of the numerator seem to be forming a pattern. Can you share the code to generate $S_{N+1}$?

@jblood94 I have coded up an algorithm in Python, giving results in decimal form. I was able to get the fractions by multiplying the output with elements of this series
https://oeis.org/search?q=1%2c4%2c72%2c288%2c86400%2c1036800%20id:375251 ,
which appears to be the denominators of "my" series (modulo some multiplication by 2 or 4)

so, indeed I think we have a pattern for the denominators from https://oeis.org/search?q=1%2c4%2c72%2c288%2c86400%2c1036800%20id:375251. What is your insight about the numerators?

It can be solved with generating functions. Set $s_0 = 0$, and write the recursion as $$(n+1)s_{n+1} = \sum_{r \ge 0} 2^{-r} \sum_{j_1+j_2+\dots+j_r=n} s_{j_1} \cdot s_{j_2} \cdots s_{j_r}.$$ Let $f = \sum_{n \ge 0} s_nx^n$. Convince yourself that the RHS is the coefficient of $x^n$ in $\sum_{r \ge 0} (f/2)^r$. The LHS is the ceofficient of $x^n$ in $f'$. Hence $f$ satisfies the differential equation $$f' = \frac{1}{1 - f/2}, \quad f(0) = 0.$$ Use your favorite technique to obtain $f = 2 - 2\sqrt{1 - x}$. Using the generating function of the Catalan numbers, you can easily derive $$f = \sum_{n \ge 0} \frac{1}{4^n(n+1)}\binom{2n}{n} x^{n+1} \implies s_n = \frac{1}{4^{n-1}n}\binom{2n-2}{n-1}, \quad n \ge 1.$$

Brilliant, really! Indeed, I was looking for a generating function approach, but given my inexperience in the matter, I did not consider putting derivatives into play. Thanks a lot! :)

Also, your solution was explained very clearly and thanks to this I could follow the answer step-by-step. That is very much appreciated :)
